# How is a yaml file suppposed to load in my Python script?

Tags: python, scripting, pyyaml

I'm trying to clone a remote repo, open a certain yaml file, update a couple keys, then stage and push it back to remote. But I can't stage nor commit the file, since my script seems to be ignoring my updates.

**I load the file and add the keys I want to update into a `update_values` variable**

```
yaml_file_path = "build.yml"
try:

    with open(yaml_file_path, 'r') as file:
        data = yaml.safe_load(file)


    update_values = {
        'key1': 'q700mb',
        'key2': 'xyz',
    }
```

**then try to "write" the updates back into it**

```
    for key, value in update_values.items():
        if key in data:
            data[key] = value

    
    with open(yaml_file_path, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(data, file)

except Exception as e:
    print("error when touching the YAML file: {e}")
```

My commit fails stating there is nothing to be updated. Then I open and log the content of the file I expect to be update, just to check

```
print("updated yaml file: ")
with open(yaml_file_path,'r') as file:
    updated_yaml = file.read()
    print(updated_yaml)
```

But everything remains untouched

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sure. Just updated it

Comment: you didn't say which of the yaml libraries you have used not which data has been given before you tried to update the data. You have at least one condition in your code; have you checked that those keys where given? If not you wouldn't update and then - of course - nothing would change.